# Using '<path>' and GET forms on Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I have a configuration in my app that goes something like this:

```
@app.route("/path/<path:sub_path>", methods = ['GET'])
def path(sub_path):
    print("Subpath is: " + str(sub_path))
    return 1
```

And a form that looks something like:

```
  <form role="form" class="" action="http://localhost:5000/path/<path:sub_path>" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="sub_path" id="sub_path" placeholder="Search 2..">
      <input type = "submit" value = "submit" />
  </form>
```

However, the print statement returns `"Subpath is: <path:sub_path>".`
How can I properly send the URL using the GET method?

Comment: What do you mean by _send the URL using the GET method?_ Not directly related to your question, but why the `return 1`?

Comment: You question is actually not clear, what you want to achieve here exactly ? If you could provide some more details regarding your question ?